# Creating Pandas dataframe from multiple json files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a directory full of JSON files that I need to extract information from and convert into a Pandas dataframe. My current solution works, but I have a feeling that there is a more elegant way of doing this:

```
for entry in os.scandir(directory):
    if entry.path.endswith(".json"):
        with open(entry.path) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            ...
            newline = field1 + ',' + field2 + ',' + ... +  ',' + fieldn
            output.append(newline)
...
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(output)))
```

Comment: where is `data` being used?

Comment: why not read each json into dataframe and combine all these dataframes into one big dataframe

Comment: yeah I'd check out [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) and [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: data is the source for all the values (field1, field2, ...) that I need to store in a df. I basically convert data into a comma separated value string to be used later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be done better.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

all_files = glob(os.path.join(path, "*.json"))
ind_df = (pd.read_json(f) for f in all_files)
df = pd.concat(ind_df, ignore_index=True)
```

Using generators will save a lot of computation and memory.